# Enable ExecuteCommand on AWS Fargate via cdk in a ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

Currently have configured AWS Fargate service with [ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ecs-patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html) via AWS CDK(Python), would like to enable ExecuteCommand on the fargate containers to get access over them.

But currently unable to find a method to enable Exec on this fargate service.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One can now enable execute command via CDK:

```
declare const cluster: ecs.Cluster;
const loadBalancedFargateService = new ecsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(this, 'Service', {
  cluster,
  memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
  desiredCount: 1,
  cpu: 512,
  taskImageOptions: {
    image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry("amazon/amazon-ecs-sample"),
  },
  enableExecuteCommand: true
});
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns-readme.html#ecs-exec

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needs the command to enable shell access from the cli.

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster <cluster_name> --service <service_name> --task-definition <task_definition_name> --enable-execute-command --force-new-deployment
```

On a bit of a side note: You will also need to create a custom AWS Service: ecs-tasks role that includes Systems Manager permissions in addition to the AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy that comes in the default ecs-tasks role ecsTaskExecutionRole.

Here's an example policy.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
            "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel",
            "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
            "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be an open issue/feature request in the aws-cdk repo that describes your [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/15197).

The workaround is using Escape Hatches:

```
cfn_service = self.web_service.service.node.default_child
cfn_service.add_override("Properties.EnableExecuteCommand", True)
```

From my experience I learned that the ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService is still limited. In some cases it makes sense to use the FargateService and create the loadbalancer, portmappings,... yourself.